# bash script to append word to filenames

Tags: bash, filenames

I'm trying append to word "dicom" to the front of many filenames in a set of folders. The folders all begin with "s" (referred to by "s*" in the script below), and each contain many files (specified by "*" below)--I'd like all of these files to be changed using this bash script. I tried to run this:

```
for file in /Volumes/USB_AIB/DICOMFunCurrentBatch/MOVr1unzip/s*/*
  do
  mv $file dicom${file%%}
done
```

but got thousands of lines of the following error (once for each file within each folder--this is just an example of one of them):

```
mv: rename /Volumes/USB_AIB/DICOMFunCurrentBatch/MOVr1unzip/s307_1/29217684 to dicom/Volumes/USB_AIB/DICOMFunCurrentBatch/MOVr1unzip/s307_1/29217684: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. the following variable expansion `${file%%}` is strange because it does nothing:

   ${parameter%%word} : remove the longest matching suffix pattern.
2. to move the file into a directory the path should exists, to create the path:

   mkdir -p "$(dirname "${newfilename}")"

Maybe what you are trying to do:

```
for file in /Volumes/USB_AIB/DICOMFunCurrentBatch/MOVr1unzip/s*/*
do
    mv "$file" "${file%/*}/dicom${file##*/}"
done
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't you have a valid path as `dicom/Volumes/USB_AIB/DICOMFunCurrentBatch/MOVr1unzip/s307_1/`, why do you add `dicom` at the beginning?

maybe you want to append `dicom` to the end of the `$file`?

```
mv "$file" "${file}_dicom"
```

or something like that.

Comment: Need to append to file name. Thanks